# Unable to run SOQL queries

Tags: soql, error, error-messages

UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379

The above error keeps showing up each time I attempt to run a query on Workbench, for any object in Salesforce. Regardless if I use different API versions to authenticate.

It started happening 3 weeks ago and it is affecting multiple users who previously had no problems running queries from Workbench.

Comment: Does it occur on workbench?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, it did not solve the problem.